# Laravel Logic in language files

Tags: php, laravel, localization, laravel-5

I am trying to do the following:

```
return array(
    ...
    'hello' => 'Sehr geehrte '.($last_name ? ':salutation' . $last_name : 'Damen und Herren').',',
    ...
);
```

But this doesn't work as it says that $last_name is undefined (it is passed into the file however).

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can do two language element like following ...

```
return array(
    ...
    'hello_with_name' => 'Sehr geehrte :salutation :last_name Damen und Herren',
    'hello' => 'Sehr geehrte :salutation Damen und Herren'
    ...
);
```

You can call the language items as follows ..

```
{{trans('language_file_name.hello_with_name', array('salutation' => $salutation, 'last_name' => $last_name)}}

{{trans('language_file_name.hello', array('salutation' => $salutation)}}
```